# Animation: Make object visible

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I have a curve wich is a graph of something. Now I want to animate the graph to get larger by the time and then being fully visible. Hard to describe, I mean something like this without kamera movement: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jJqYwrjt6s
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to animated the bevel end factor of a curve object.

**Step 1**: Add curve and change its shape in edit mode.

[image]

[image]

**Step 2**: Set key frames for the bevel end factor in the curves panel

[image]

And the result:

[image]

Comment: I prefer this method over Bertmoog's since it can be done directly with curve objects, and doesn't require destructively converting them to mesh.

Comment: Me too +1 :)  But my "curve" was just a mesh from the start.